# How to create index mapping in elasticsearch for Java ArrayList

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Having a model class which is represtented like below,

```
class Search{

int id,
List<User> users;
}

class User{
int id,
String name;
}
```

For the mentioned class i would like to create mapping in elasticSearch and was wondering how to achieve the same.Googled everywhere but i couldn't get any, since i am very much new to elasticsearch.

I have pasted an incompleted index mapping below and requesting help to achieve the complete model mapping in elasticsearch.

```
PUT user_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "user_map": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Depends on your use case, you can just let ES automap it for you in which case it will be an array or you can specify a nested mapping https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make **users** a `nested` type and add the rest of the properties in there. Even, if you dont add properties of users, it would auto map them. Important thing is making users nested.

```
   PUT user_index
    {  
     "mappings":{  
      "users":{  
         "type":"nested",
         "properties":{  
            "id":{  
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "name":{  
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{  
                  "keyword":{  
                     "type":"keyword"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Refer : [Using nested fields for arrays of objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects)